# Adding a focus state to a div inside a link

Tags: html, css, focus, accessibility, pseudo-class

I'm trying to make the link have a focus state around the whole .container-covid-alert div, when the link is tabbed onto, I'm sure this must be possible? The below 2 selectors are not working.

```css
.container-covid-alert:focus {
                outline: solid 3px #FFAD16;
            }
            .container-covid-alert a:focus {
                outline: solid 3px #FFAD16;
            }
            .container-covid-alert {
                background-color: #206497 !important;
                color: #FFFFFF;
                padding-top: 10px;
                padding-bottom: 10px;
                display: block;
                flex-flow: row wrap;
                align-items: center;
                align-content: center;
                justify-content: flex-start;
                font-size: 1.1rem;
            }
            .container-covid-alert a {
                color: #FFFFFF;
            }
            .covid-inner {
                margin: auto;
                width: 1170px;
            }
```

```html
<a id="covid-banner-link" title="Coronavirus" class="sys_16" href="/">
    <div class="container-covid-alert">
    <div class="covid-inner">
    <p>Coronavirus (COVID-19)updates and advice.</p>
    </div>
    </div>
    </a>
```

Comment: Difficult to understand what you exactly want.

Answer (score 0):

Your hyperlink collapses as it behaves as an inline element.

The solution is to make it act like a block element with `display: block;`.

That way you can just add the `:focus` state to the hyperlink itself and make it really simple.

Also an [orange focus indicator is not high enough contrast](https://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/?fcolor=FFAD16&bcolor=FFFFFF) - it is only 1.86:1 and you need 3:1 as a minimum so you may want to change that.

```css
#covid-banner-link{
   display:block;
}

#covid-banner-link:focus {
   outline: solid 3px #FFAD16;          
}

.container-covid-alert {
                background-color: #206497 !important;
                color: #FFFFFF;
                padding-top: 10px;
                padding-bottom: 10px;
                display: block;
                flex-flow: row wrap;
                align-items: center;
                align-content: center;
                justify-content: flex-start;
                font-size: 1.1rem;
            }
            .container-covid-alert a {
                color: #FFFFFF;
            }
            .covid-inner {
                margin: auto;
                width: 1170px;
            }
```

```html
<a id="covid-banner-link" title="Coronavirus" class="sys_16" href="/">
<div class="container-covid-alert">
<div class="covid-inner">
<p>Coronavirus (COVID-19)updates and advice.</p>
</div>
</div>
</a>
```